# SVM kernel for detecting if a substring appears in some given string

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel

I'm trying to do the exercise in 16.1 in the book *Understanding Machine Learning*, Ben-David, et al. formulated as follows:

> Consider the task of learning to find a sequence of characters
> ("signature") in a file that indicates whether it contains a virus or
> not and let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all finite strings over some
> alphabet set $\Sigma$, and let $\mathcal{X}_d$ be the set of all such
> strings of length at most $d$. The learning hypothesis class is
> $\mathcal{H}=\lbrace h_v: v\in\mathcal{X}_d\rbrace$, where, for a
> string $x\in\mathcal{X}$, $h_v(x)$ is $1$ iff $v$ is a substring of
> $x$ (and $h_v(x) = −1$ otherwise).
>
> Let $s = |\mathcal{X}_d|$ and consider a mapping $\psi$ to a space
> $R^s$, so that each coordinate of $\psi (x)$ corresponds to some
> string $v$ and indicates whether $v$ is a substring of $x$ (that is,
> for every $x \in \mathcal{X}, \psi(x)$ is a vector in $\lbrace
> > 0,1\rbrace^{|\mathcal{X}_d|}$). Note that the dimension of this
> feature space is exponential in $d$.

Given that information, I need to show that every member of the class $\mathcal{H}$ can be realized by composing a linear classifier over $\psi (x)$, and, moreover, by such a halfspace whose norm is 1 and that attains a margin of 1.

However, I was confused over the $v$ in the definition of $\mathcal{H}=\lbrace h_v: v\in\mathcal{X}_d\rbrace$. My understanding is that this $v$ denotes any string $v\in\mathcal{X}_d$ not just some fixed string. Suppose my understanding is correct then denote by $v_1, v_2,..., v_s$ all strings in $\mathcal{X}_d$ and then we can define $\psi$ by

$$
\psi(x) =
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{v_1}(x) \\
h_{v_s}(x) \\
\vdots \\
h_{v_s}(x)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Thus we have $h_{v_i}(x)=\psi (x)_i$ (the i(th)-element of $\psi (x)$). But I don't see any the linear classifiers in this equation let alone the margin and the norm constraints?